# Ubuntu on virtualbox : How to create VDI on a drive other than C:\ drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu11.04 on VirtualBox4.1.20.0 and my host machine is windows 7.

- Installed VirtualBox on my D:\ (Windows 7 is on C:\ )
- While trying to install Ubuntu, the VDI (VirtualBox Disk Image) gets automatically created at V:\Documents and Setings\ ...\My Documents\VirtualBox VMs\myUbuntu\myUbuntu.vdi
- The problem is that I don't have a lot of free space on my C:\ and wish to have the Virtual Hard Disk on D:\ instead of C:\ , but there seems to be no option to do that during installation.

Any ideas?

P.S What I am doing is pretty similar to this [this](http://www.deltalounge.net/wpress/2011/06/installing-ubuntu-11-04-in-virtualbox/)

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It is not programming related.

Comment: Asking an off-topic question.

Comment: http://www.deltalounge.net/wpress/wp-content/gallery/virtualbox-ubuntu-1104/virtualboxubuntu-8.jpg u should select the drive from this location to where ever u want to install

Comment: But yours was a comment..how do I accept that? :)

Comment: i have made it into an answer now

Comment: I'll accept it in 5 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.deltalounge.net/wpress/wp-content/gallery/virtualbox-ubuntu-1104/virtualboxubuntu-8.jpg… u should select the drive from this location to where ever u want to install